# GIMP 2.8 Install Problem - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, gimp

I wanted to install the new **Gimp** release, as it came out officially some time ago. I've had the old 2.6 version installed on my **Ubuntu 12.04** and removed it. Then I've updated ( **sudo apt-get update** ). Now when I want to install Gimp over the **terminal** as normally ( **sudo apt-get install gimp** ) I have this problem that it always installs the old 2.6 version instead of the new 2.8

Is there something wrong with the PPA or how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. By the way, is this the official PPA for the new Gimp release?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know))) But that only one way to install GIMP 2.8 that I found in internet when I was installing it on my PC. So I think, the answer is yes)

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked today for a 14.04 install under i3WM without any problems. Just reporting for further users looking for information.